# Google Tag Manager trigger using dataLayer wont fire

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Button:

```
<button id="btnBuy" onclick="SendData();"
```

JavaScript function:

```
<script>
// Measure a view of product details. This example assumes the detail view occurs on pageload,
// and also tracks a standard pageview of the details page.
var dataLayer = [];

dataLayer.push( {
  'ecommerce': {
    'detail': {
      'actionField': {'list': 'Apparel Gallery'},    // 'detail' actions have an optional list property.
      'products': [{
      'name': '@GetString("Ecom:Product.Name")',         // Name or ID is required.
      'id': '@GetValue("Ecom:Product.Number")',
      'price': '@GetValue("Ecom:Product.ActualPriceWithVAT")',
      'brand': '@GetString("Ecom:Manufacturer.Name")',
      'category': 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'
       }]
     }
   }
});

function SendData()
{
    var purchaseData = 
    dataLayer.push( {
        'event': 'addToCart',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'SEK',
            'add': {                                // 'add' actionFieldObject measures.
                'products': [{                        //  adding a product to a shopping cart.
                    'name': '@GetString("Ecom:Product.Name")',
                    'id': '@GetValue("Ecom:Product.Number")',
                    'price': '@GetValue("Ecom:Product.ActualPriceWithVAT")',
                    'brand': '@GetString("Ecom:Manufacturer.Name")',
                    'category': 'Apparel',
                    'variant': $j('input[name=radioDim1]:checked').val(),
                    'quantity': $j( '#QuantitySelector option:selected' ).val(),
                    'size': $j( 'input[name=radioDim2]:checked' ).closest( 'label' ).text()
                }]
            }
        }
    } );

    return purchaseData;

}

</script>
```

Tag info:
Tracking: Event
Category: Add to cart
Action: {{Event}}
Label: {{Page Path}}

Trigger:
Event equals addToCart

I am using the Preview mode in Chrome and even though it registers my click event it does not say that the trigger is fired.

[image: Tag manager Variables]

[image: Tag Manager Data Layer]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code above comes after the GTM container snippet, what you've done in the first line is to redefine the dataLayer, ie.

```
var dataLayer = [];
```

This wipes out the dataLayer as GTM knows it to be, and potentially breaks your tags.

You should define the dataLayer it in a safer manner like this, for example:

```
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];
```

so as to not wipe it out if it already exists.

Comment: To me that doesn't make any sense. I have to declare the variable as an empty array and then push the object into this array. Isnt that how its done?

How about the SendData function which is called when someone adds a product to the cart. Is the purchase variable supposed to be returned or is it enough to just add another object into the array?

Answer (score 1):

On the left you can see actually the event names which were fired, so "addToCart" is definitely fired.

You should screenshot the "Tags" tab, and click on your tag which you would like to observe, then there is info about why or why not it is fired.